# jQuery without a browser

Tags: jquery, cross-platform, executable

Forgive the naive question, but is there a jQuery-compatible HTML renderer that is not a browser? Preferably OS independent.

My point being that browsers do much more than just render the DOM and run scripts, but I'd like something that does only that part; no internet-based features required.

Comment: To run JS outside the browser you can use Node.
I don't see the value of using Jquery outisde DOM manipulation though.

Comment: What are you even talking about?  A "jQuery executable"?  What would that even do?  jQuery doesn't have anything to do with rendering the DOM or executing scripts.  That's... what a browser does.

Comment: Ok maybe I see your point: you want to get a generic container, just in charge of rendering right?

Comment: @pietro909 - Yes, essentially the rendering part of a browser but stand alone.

Comment: I'm sorry but the way you asked it is wrong: I edited your question and provided an answer. JQuery in this case is just a library, what you are looking for is for the runtime environment for a webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure about what is your goal, but if you are looking for a cross-platform container for webapps which is not a browser you could check [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).

Comment: I didn't have time recently, but now I've looked into this and its exactly what I was looking for; thanks for letting me know!